# In the Goblet of Fire video game, was Stanley Townsend’s character actually Barty Crouch Jr?

Tags: harry-potter, video-games

In the Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire video game, Alastor Moody was voiced by Stanley Townsend and Barty Crouch Jr was voiced by Sam Hazeldine.

However, the Harry Potter Wiki lists Alastor Moody’s appearance in the video game as

Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire (video game) (Polyjuiced body only)

Polyjuiced body ONLY! So that must mean that Stanley Townsend must have voiced Barty Crouch Jr (in a Polyjuiced state), right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they just mean that Alastor Moody (regardless of who was piloting the body) was voiced by Stanley Townsend and Barty Crouch Jr was voiced by Sam Hazeldine.

Comment: How is this opinion-based?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the equivalent of having a conversation about Lindsay Lohan and Jamie Lee Curtis in Freaky Friday. It's just about semantics.

As we all know, Moody in GOF is Barty Crouch Jr.

The real Moody has no lines and is only seen once.

So TECHNICALLY Stanley Townshend voiced Barty Crouch Jr. (Moody Form) and Sam Hazeldine voiced Barty Crouch Jr. (Barty Form).